# Coding Better Object-Oriented JavaScript with Closure Compiler full example code

Tags: javascript, optimization, compiler-construction, closures

I like the ideas presented by Hedger Wang in his post "Coding Better Object-Oriented JavaScript with Closure Compiler" http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/coding-better-object-oriented-javascript-with-closure-compiler/, but his examples don't cover everything, and some examples seem to use a different style than other examples. I have been searching the web for solutions to specific problems, and I have found some, but each solution seems to be incompatible with some other piece of the puzzle.

Can anyone provide a complete working example that covers all of the following SIMULTANEOUSLY:

- Uses Google's Closure Compiler with Advanced Optimizations on
- Uses annotations, including @type, @constructor, @enum...
- Uses externs files for external library (jQuery for example)
- Exports a user defined library "class" and all its "public functions" (and includes the externs file for this class)
- Has another "class", in its own file, that uses the library without having to recompile that library
- Avoids present and future naming collisions (namespacing?)
- Avoids globals as much as possible (1 per file seems like a reasonable target to me. The global name can appear multiple times - I don't mind doing one search and replace per file, but I wouldn't want to do more than one such operation)
- Includes command lines to use to compile the whole thing
- Doesn't have errors or warnings
- Example of inheritance, interface,... would be nice, but I can live without these for now

Okay, I know that is a bit of a list, which is why I am having trouble getting everything to work together, but that seems to me to be the basic requirements of a medium to large project. I will continue to bang my head against the wall for a while, but if someone has already done such a project, I would be eternally grateful for a peek.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these videos.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3uWx-fhjUc

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJ-vTq4lp10

All are about google Closure.

You can also check out this book. It rocks

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920001416.do

Answer (score 0):

My Closure Compiler + KnockoutJS boilerplate covers most of your bullets. [Check it out](https://github.com/batilc1/gcc-knockout).